Primeng locale 'ar-AE' not working for p-inputNumber
I have used primeng version 14.0.0 and I have to visualize a list of currencies in the number input field.
en-US and many more currency types are working fine. But if the currency type is AED and the locale is ar-AE the form control is broken.
  <p-inputNumber
            id="retailValue"
            formControlName="retailValue"
            mode="currency"
            [currency]="currency"
            [locale]="locale">
  </p-inputNumber>

Here, locale and the currency variables in the component.ts file are as follows
locale: string = 'ar-AE';

currency: string = 'AED';

Please help me with this.

It worked for me .. example with updated locale from docs

Can you please elaborate on what is exactly the issue when you mention form control is broken?

@KcH you have used the latest primeng version, is it working for the 14.0.0 version?

@Tejeshree when you enter backspace or any number it will add two '00' to the amount. ex: first i will enter 3 , then it will display as 300.00 then adding any other number or backspace it will be 30,000.00

I have to check it in 14.0.0 ... will try it, yes it has issues with inputting and also the backspace ... no GH issues on the same as well weird
